# tapering/mitering table legs on a table saw without someone helping

Tags: woodworking

I have just built my tool to taper/miter wood on my tablesaw - I am making a library table and need to taper the legs.  The tool works beautifully, BUT, when I get to almost the end, the piece I am tapering, lifts up and doesn't cut right.  What can I do to avoid this if I do NOT have someone on the other end to hold the wood flat???

Comment: Such a purpose-built "tool" is called a Jig.  Also, did you know there was a [Woodworking.SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/) ?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say knowing nothing about your current setup, but it's common to keep your workpiece longer than needed during difficult cuts like that, and then trim the piece to length, eliminating the imperfect segment.

Otherwise, the right set of [push sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_saw#Avoiding_kickback) should make the job safer and easier.

Comment: ^^ that, plus google "hold downs".